# How to trigger a service function from an Application lifecycle event in Nativescript + angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have a Nativescript+angular application with some services. One service needs to do something when the application goes to the background and foreground.

How can I trigger a function of the service instance on the application lifecycle events?

This is my main.ts were I listen to the lifecycle events:

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import { on as applicationOn, suspendEvent, resumeEvent, ApplicationEventData } from "application";

applicationOn(suspendEvent, function (args: ApplicationEventData) {
    //Trigger method performGoToBackgroundChecks of RemoteService
    console.log("App goes to background");
});

applicationOn(resumeEvent, function (args: ApplicationEventData) {
    //Trigger method performGoToForegroundChecks of RemoteService
    console.log("App goes to foreground");
});

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Code below is from remote.service.ts with only the relevant code for this question. The service contains logic that is used in different pages. I want to trigger the performGoToBackgroundChecks and performGoToForegroundChecks.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class RemoteService {

    public performGoToBackgroundChecks(){
    }

    public performGoToForegroundChecks(){
    }
}
```

I can also add the application lifecycle event handlers in the remote.service.ts file, but I don't know how to access the service instance to trigger it's public functions.

Comment: i typically add the lifecycle hooks per page that needs them, that then allows for calling methods from other files

Comment: Can you give an example? I don't know how to invoke a method from the instances that are created by angular: Angular will create an instance of the RemoteService that is injected where needed.. how can I access that instance from those lifecycle hooks?

Comment: if you move the lifecycle hooks into the class constructors, they are easier to use and control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mast3rd3mon pointed out, I got it to work by moving the application lifecycle hooks inside the constructor of the Service that needs them.

This is my working code of RemoteService.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import { on as applicationOn, suspendEvent, resumeEvent, ApplicationEventData } from "application";

@Injectable()
export class RemoteService {

    constructor() {


        applicationOn(suspendEvent, (args: ApplicationEventData) => {
            this.performGoToBackgroundChecks();
        });

        applicationOn(resumeEvent, (args: ApplicationEventData)=> {
            this.performGoToForegroundChecks();
        });
    }

    public performGoToBackgroundChecks(){
        console.log("in remoteService instance -- goto background");
    }

    public performGoToForegroundChecks(){
        console.log("in remoteService instance -- goto foreground");
    }
}
```

Comment: I obtain this.performGoToBackgroundChecks(); is not a function

Comment: @Kerby82 Have you tried the non-edited answer? It uses self=this in the constructor and self.performGoToBackgroundChecks() in the function call.